# How to remove the Extranet notification bar

Tags: notifications

I have in my organization two types of users, internal and external, because of that we're facing the notification ribbon bar fixed at top page show the following message:
"Welcome . This is an extranet site and please share information responsibly. Please click here for details about  external sharing guidelines."

Basically I would like to remove (deactivate) this ribbon bar.